# Preloaded image reloads when assigning to a different container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, preload

Im preloading images like so:

```
function preload(src) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        alert("Img is ready");
        $("body").css("background-image", "url(" + src + ")");
    };
    img.src = src;
}

function loadBG() {
    //Get BG and check if it contains "_min" at the end, if yes, we know
    //its a compressed image so we start loading the original
    var bgUrl = $("body").css('background-image');
    bgUrl = bgUrl.match(/\/([^.\/]+)\./);
    console.log(bgUrl[1]);
    //Start loading
    if(bgUrl[1].indexOf("_min") !== -1) {
       var src = BASE_URL + "assets/" + bgUrl[1].replace("_min", ".jpg");
       console.log(src);
       preload(src);
    }
}
```

where `loadBG()` is initiated from `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`.

Ive also tried the Jquery way of doing this:

```
function preload(src) {
    //Create img elem
    var img = $("<img/>");
    //Attach listener
    img.ready(function() {
         $("body").css("background-image", "url(" + src + ")");
         $(this).remove();
    });
    //Add src and hide, then append to start loading
    img.attr("src", src);
    img.css("display", "none");
    $("body").append(img);
}
```

But the issue remains the same (read below).

The loading works well, but when the `.onload()` is fired and the image is assigned as a background on `body`, the image is actually served and downloaded **again**. I can confirm this by looking in the network tab of the console (there are 3 background images loaded - the compressed [default] one, and the "preloaded" twice, once when initiated by code and second once it's assigned as a new background image on body), as well as seeing a flickering. Why is this? Is there a way to preload these images in this manner without it actually being loaded another time?

Comment: What's the http response code from the second request?  Edit: I'm assuming it will most likely be a 304 Not Modified

Comment: @Taplar 200 from all of them, so it's not even like it reloads because it has been unsuccessful.

Comment: Out of curiosity, check your network request for the image.  Take a look at the `Cache-Control` and `Expires` response headers.  I'm wondering if the server is not returning the correct headers to allow the images to be cached by the browser.

Comment: And are any of these images public facing that we could reference directly and test with?

Comment: `Cache-Control: no-cache` even if my caching is turned on and I can't find `Expires`. turning `Disable cache` off reduces the flickering however even then its visible occasionally. the assets I cant make public but I am using ~2.9MB ~5800x3800px pictures and their compressed counterparts (which are about 250kb)

Comment: `Cache-Control: no-cache`, to me, is why you're not getting a 304.  The server isn't allowing the images to cache.